# angularjs currency filter add extra plus symbol in front

Tags: angularjs, filter, currency

I'm using the filter the following way in html.

```
var mydata = 20000;

{{mydata | currency : '$' : 2}}
```

however, the value shows as +20,000.00
It has one extra "+" for the value.

Is there a way to remove that?

Thanks!

Comment: where do you get the `+` from?

Comment: I have no idea. I read through their source code. It seems like it is from $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.

Comment: what do you want to have? If you don't need a symbol, why are you setting it to currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that you're not overwriting the default currency symbol somewhere in your code. See the following example.

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('root', []);

app.run(["$locale", function ($locale) {
  $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = "+"
}]);

app.component('root', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <!-- Prints out $20,000 -->
    {{ $ctrl.myData | currency: "$": 2 }}
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Prints out +20,000 -->
    {{ $ctrl.myDataPlus | currency }}
  </div>
  `,
  controller: function() {
    this.myData = "20000";
    this.myDataPlus = "20000";
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="root">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <root></root>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not overwriting it anywhere. not sure how it happened.

Answer (score 0):

need to overwrite $locale number format.

```
appRun.$inject = ['$locale'];
function appRun ($locale) {
  $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1].posPre = '$';
}
```